# Which plugin will let me decide what users have access to on their side bar in wp-admin?

Tags: plugins, admin

I want to customize the editor role so that they only have access to 'pages, posts, comments, profiles'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried quite a few different ones, I always come back to the one that works best:
[Justin Tadlock's Members Plugin.](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/)

It's very easy to use right out of the box. It has predefined roles, or you can create your own user roles with about every option available in WordPress.

Comment: This plugin is very simple and easy to get going. Thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Adminimize. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminimize/

Comment: I also like this one because of the amount of customization options it gives you.